# Connect to GIT Repo on Windows Machine from Linux VM

Tags: git, ssl

I am trying to access a GIT repository located on a Windows machine from a Linux box. This is what I have done so far.

1. Installed/Configured Windows GIT server.
2. Created a Repository on Windows machine.
3. Have GIT installed on Linux VM
4. Trying to connect to Git Repository located under C drive in Windows machine.

While I try to access the repository I am running into SSL certificate issues, please see the error below. I tried different options to provide a complete path

Error:-
   fatal: unable to access 'https://xx.xx.xx.xx/C/GitRepo/GitRepo/': Peer's Certificate has expired
   fatal: unable to access 'https://firstname.lastname@xx.xx.xx.xx(Windows Server IP)/C/GitRepo/GitRepo/': Issuer certificate is invalid
   fatal: unable to access 'https://firstname.lastname@xx.xx.xx.xx(Windows Server IP)/C/GitRepo/GitRepo/': Unable to communicate securely with peer: requested domain name does not match the server's certificate.
   ssh: connect to host xx.xx.xx.xx(Windows Server IP)  port 22: Connection refused

Troubleshooting Steps:-
 I tried different options. Disable SSL verification, Provide a complete path to the .pem file. None of them worked. Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Please update your post. It's not clear what is installed/configured. Do you access/run https server or ssh sever on port 22? Can you access the server from windows? Did you check certificates - are these correct? Is your CA t rusted?

Comment: GIT is installed on a windows server and I am trying to access the GIT repository that is located on Windows server from a Linux box with https and it throws the certificate errors that I posted earlier.

Comment: Do you access/run https server or ssh sever on port 22? Yes, SSH server is on port 22. 
Can you access the server from windows? - Yes. I can ping the Linux server from Windows.
Did you check certificates - are these correct? Yes, the certificate is renewed and expired cert is removed from IIS (Windows Internet Information Services)
Is your CA t rusted?

Comment: Is your CA t rusted? - How do I check that? I am not sure what cert store GIT is reading the certificates from. This is the biggest issue. 
In Linux GIT config I provided absolute path to the certificate but no still getting same issues. I also set the sslverify = false in GIT config but still running into the certs issues.